# Modeling objects in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to create/mock a "class" in AngularJS to predefine properties, constructor, and methods. I would like to create a vanilla JavaScript "class" file but how to include it in AngularJS project?

```
var Pastry = {
  // initialize the pastry
  init: function (type, flavor, levels, price, occasion) {
    this.type = type;
    this.flavor = flavor;
    this.levels = levels;
    this.price = price;
    this.occasion = occasion;
  },

  // Describe the pastry
  describe: function () {
    var description = "The " + this.type + " is a " + this.occasion + " pastry, has a " + this.flavor + " flavor, " + this.levels + " layer(s), and costs " + this.price + ".";
    return description;
  }
};
```

or

```
function Pastry(type, flavor, levels, price, occasion) {
  this.type = type;
  this.flavor = flavor;
  this.levels = levels;
  this.price = price;
  this.occasion = occasion;
}

Pastry.prototype.describe = function () {
  var description = "The " + this.type + " is a " + this.occasion + "pastry, has a " + this.flavor + " flavor, " + this.levels + " layer(s), and costs " + this.price + ".";
  return description;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would pick the second example for JavaScript objects use *prototype inheritance*. So using that will give you the most *class-like* code. However the `class` keyword is not exclusive to AngularJS and is a different way to write *Constructor Functions* with prototypical inherited methods, getters and setters.

Use `import` and `export` ([JS modules guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)) to use a `class` or any other value in other files. Define with `export` which variables, functions or classes can be *exported*. In another file use `import` at the top of your file to import the exported value to your own file.

So putting it all together.
You can still choose to do it with the `function` keyword and manually write your `prototype` object.

```
function Pastry(type, flavor, levels, price, occasion) {
  ...
}

Pastry.prototype.describe = function () {
  ...
}

export default Pastry;
```

Or do it with the `class` keyword. The end result will be almost exactly the same.

```
export default class Pastry {

  constructor(type, flavor, levels, price, occasion) {
    ...
  }

  describe() {
    ...
  }

}
```

Notice the `default` keyword. It will indicate that as long as we don't specify values that we want to import the default value should be imported.

```
import Pastry from './pastry.js';
```

The `from` keyword retrieves the values from a path relative to the file it is in. So in this case above the `pastry.js` file is in the same directory is the file with the `import` statement.

Comment: OK, but how can I use the Import in my AngularJS controller? wherever I put it I get a parsing error.

Comment: Post your controller code and how you implement my answer to your original question. What kind of error do you get?

Comment: I made a separate file for the class in the same folder as the Ctrl
`((ns) => {

    "use strict";

    angular.module("module-name").controller("Ctrl", [dependecies..., Ctrl]);

    function Ctrl(dependecies...) {

        let vm = this;
        Import Pastery from './Pastery'; <= Parsing Error
`

Comment: I did it with `let Pastry = require('./Pastry');`
Thanks a lot, you helped me with the bigger problem.
Cheers!

Comment: Ah, you are welcome. I forgot to mention that you have to do your imports at the top of the file.

Comment: One more update to finalize this theme and round up. To `import` an external `class` file in wanted AngularJS Controller/Directive just `import ClassName from './path'` in front of Controllers/Directives IIFE. It works like a charm!